# Table 'my_table' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4

If I try

```
select * from my_table
```

I get:

```
"Table 'my_table' doesn't exist in engine"
```

but

```
show tables
```

contains this table in the list.

I tried:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --check --all-databases
```

but also get

```
Table 'my_table' doesn't exist in engine
```

Database version:

```
Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

I checked `/var/lib/mysql/mydatabase` – *.frm and *.ibd for certain tables exist

***UDPATE:***
I tried this query:

```
select * from innodb_table_stats
Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist in engine
```

Comment: you should check if the table name has a space before3 or behind it.

Comment: Underscores and other characters may be different to what you are using too.

Comment: Also check `SHOW TABLE STATUS;`